# Finding values in column that are substrings of other values

Tags: mysql

I have a table that contains ~600000 items, identified by an ID and a barcode.

Some of these barcodes are duplicate, but not exactly, as some have a prefix and some don't (e.g. 7290001234567 Vs. 1234567)

I need to find all items whose barcodes are the same, with and without the prefix - output should be something like:

```
id  barcode
1   7290001234567
2   1234567
...
```

I tried the following but it cannot work as the subquery returns multiple items and it breaks the function:

```
select * 
  from item 
 where barcode like concat("%", (select barcode from item where char_length(barcode) <= 8));
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please see: [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query) - I would warn you however, that SQL is not optimized for this kind of thing, so any solution is likely to be slow.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a subquery and join

```
select * 
from item 
INNER JOIN  (
  select barcode from item where char_length(barcode) <= 8)
) T ON item.barcode like concat('%', T.barcode)
```

or using a self join

```
select * 
from item i1
INNER JOIN item i2 on i1.barcode like concat('%', i2.barcode)
```

Be sure you have index  on  barcode  ..  (could be a slow query)

Comment: anyway the subquery version is for explain the right use of the subquery as  in the OP